# Getting Weird Errors While Generating Random Vectors

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

While running this code to generate a random 3D Vector:
`k.transform.position = new Vector3(Random.Range(-7.5, 7.5), Random.Range(26, 11), 140));`
I get this error:

```
CS1002: ; expected
CS1513: } expected
```

Here's the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class spawnBad : MonoBehaviour {
    public GameObject obstaclePrefab;
    public float respawnTime = 1f;
    void Start() {
        StartCoroutine(spawner);
    }

    private void spawnBad() {
        GameObject k = Instantiate(obstaclePrefab) as GameObject;
        k.transform.position = new Vector3(Random.Range(-7.5, 7.5), Random.Range(26, 11), 140));
    }

    IEnumerator spawner() {
        while (true) {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(respawnTime);
            spawnBad();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: are you going to make us guess what the error is?

Comment: sorry I'm stupid (edited).

Comment: it looks like you just have an extra `)` at the end of the line that needs to be removed.  This line - `k.transform.position = ...`

Comment: Oh I'm so dumb. I've got a couple more issues, but I should be able to work them out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
k.transform.position = new Vector3(Random.Range(-7.5, 7.5), Random.Range(26, 11), 140))
```

You have an extra `)` at the end of this line which is giving you the errors, just remove it.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to accept this, but thank you for the answer.

Comment: Don't worry its not a big deal :)